# Java - decompile & recompile - for the noobie

Tags: java, class, jar, compilation, decompiler

first time posting here so go easy on me :)

I've poked through a lot of whats here and I see a lot of indirect answers but nothing that's really pointed me in the right direction (or helped I should say).

Here's the situation, we have this java app from a now defunct company.  One of our guys managed to get the source code, but has been unavailable so I've had to resort to other measures to try and get the changes I need.  I used jd-gui to find the class file I need to modify as well as the lines (there's seriously only like 3 lines that I need to modify...).  jd-gui will save the class file as a .java file, and I'm fairly certain that if I could get the .java file back into a class file, I'd just need to use winrar to drop it back in.  As I've read here and there, getting a class file out of it isn't that simple.

I've tried using eclipse to create a new project, I tried javac which complained about some line of code that has nothing to do with anything and my guess is its really telling me that there's a function that it can't deal with because its defined in another class file, blah blah blah...

Why is this complicated?  The 'compiled' java file (class?) has references to the other class files it needs, I don't want the compiler to run the program, just put it back together and assume I got my paths right.  I'm not a programmer by nature and have been force feeding myself javascript (yes yes, not the same thing), but I seriously need to make a few minor changes and then never touch it again.

So, my question is, whats the simple solution (aside from waiting for the source code - which could be sometime between now and the eventual heat death of the universe...)

Comment: Even if you have the compiled source, that doesn't mean you have the packages that the source uses. You have to get the .jar files for those packages and import them into your Build Path in Eclipse. Only then can you rebuild that project.

Comment: try cavaj decompiler.

Comment: damn, that was quick!  So there are a bunch of jar files within the main jar file, things like 'commons-cli-1.2.jar' and a bunch of others.  is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Deepak, I'll take a look and give that a try.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, whether they are included in the original jar you decompile with jd-gui or not, you will either have to take those and put them in Eclipse, or find them online and put them into Eclipse. Regardless they must be put into your Build Path. If you could post a general example within your question, it may help generate more useful and/or thorough answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe you need a class file with your changes incorporated that you would then patch into a jar using WinRar or the like .

Try this. 
In Eclipse  go to .
Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching .

Change the settings as required. ( Remove any prompts and termination settings on compilation errors)
This is quite useful if you who want to run tests with partly written classes.
This should generate the class file you need which you could then patch in.
Good Luck!